# Menu doesn't appear in WordPress using underscores.me

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having trouble getting the "Menu" or "Navigation Menu" to appear in the header.

The code in `header.php`

```
<header>
 <?php if ( !is_front_page() ) : ?>
            <nav role="navigation" class="site-navigation main-navigation">
                <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'underscoresme' ); ?></h1>
                <div class="assistive-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'underscoresme' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'underscoresme' ); ?></a></div>
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
            </nav><!-- .site-navigation .main-navigation -->
        <?php endif; ?>
</header>
```

Menu configuration in the dashboard

[image]

Live customization

[image]

It simply doesn't want to appear. There is no `<nav>` when inspecting in dev tools. I didn't changed anything in `functions.php` or any other file that contains `PHP` code that is used to make the theme work. I want to use Bootstrap's navigation menu.

[karnopedia.com](http://karnopedia.com) is the site.

Comment: Is the header.php in the correct theme folder?

Comment: Yes, it is. You go to the site and view the page source.

Comment: It works, you just have it not showing on front page with your !is_front_page() check

Comment: Ok this is weird. The code is in the correct `header.php` and the code should be around line number ~148 but it's not there

Comment: Ok yeah, after removing `!` it works, it's there, but it should show the language switcher with a dropdown, not the pages.

Comment: Unbelievable, but I add an argument `'menu' => 'Languages'` and it works, guess the only thing I need to do, is to read the documentation about the `wp_nav_menu()` API. Anyways, could you post the answer, so I can upvote and verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the exclamation point in your !is_front_page() check. Your code works but is not displaying on front page because of the check.